# Any SQL formatter plugin for Eclipse avaialble?

Tags: sql, sql-server, eclipse, formatting

I am not finding any standard open source sql formatter eclipse plugin on net. I am using eclipse helios. I can find **Edit-->FormatSQL** but that does not seems to be working. Found one at http://ventralnet.blogspot.in/2010/11/sql-beautifier-eclipse-plugin.html
but formatting is not good. Any suggestion will be helpful. For info I am using sqlserver sql scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of my favorites are:

```
Eclipse SQL Explorer at: http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net

DBViewer at: http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/about_en.html
```

Comment: As of 16.07.2013 Eclipse SQL Explorer has no support for Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 9):

[Toad eclipse-extension](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/default.aspx) (community edition), will get you almost everything you want in an SQL editor, including formatting (ctrl+shif+f). Search for 'toad' in eclipse market place. It has very good Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL support.

Take a look at [Installation instructions and screenshots](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/w/wiki/10446.toad-extension-for-eclipse-installation.aspx).

Another option is http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/download/#eclipse (Which is very good and also has a standalone version)

Comment: wow, that was just perfect! It has auto complete too on joins which saves me lots of time

Comment: Is this free for commercial use ?

Comment: Nice plugin, despite several hiccups (NPEs are relatively frequent). Just like Toad itself, the plugin has a messy, unintuitive interface for controlling formatting options that takes a while to get used to and has rather questionable (imho) default settings, especially with respect to alignments in large queries. I haven't yet found a way to left-align everything except for a 1-tab/2-space indentation. Despite all this, it seems quite powerful and I think I'll continue trying it. @bluelurker: Yes, it's a free toad... er, tool.

Comment: The link to Toad plugin seems to be broken as of this writing. Eclipse (Oxygen) marketplace doesn't show any results.

Comment: @badbishop I spent some time evaluating the Toad Eclipse extension for my team a couple of years ago. It was almost perfect for our needs. Quest's response to a bug report I submitted was that they didn't want to spend time supporting that plugin and that they were discontinuing it. Shortly after that they removed it from the Eclipse marketplace. So that is why you are not seeing it when you search for it in the Eclipse marketplace.