# How do I Structure SQL Code like an Formatter to make it readable better by SQL Command to Database

Tags: mysql, sql, format, structure

I want to ask a SQL database to get the structured SQL code back of my query.

For example this SQL code:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name. customer_surname, customer_street 
FROM customer 
WHERE customer_name = "%benz%"
```

should be answered in a query to the SQL database like that:

```
SELECT 
    customer_id, 
    customer_name, 
    customer_surname, 
    customer_street 
FROM 
    customer 
WHERE 
    customer_name = "%benz%"
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps I think, my question can be a software patent!

Answer (score 1):

Just a note since I see no other answers (yet).

You can use a number of editors to format (aka "beautify") your SQL query. For example:

- I frequently use Squirrel SQL Client where you place the cursor in your query and type `Ctrl+Alt+F`.
- Or, you can use one of several [Eclipse plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523783/any-sql-formatter-plugin-for-eclipse-avaialble).
- Lots of other editors, but haven't seen the database doing the formatting for you.